# bash script using grep in a for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, grep

I'm trying to grep for missing values in an unzipped powerpoint doc.
I'm using this line in my script:

```
for s in *.xml; do grep -L ppaction://media "$SLIDE_PATH/${s}" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'; done
```

the script kicks an error:

```
grep /genetics/ppt/slides/: No such file or directory
grep: *.xml: No such file or directory
```

yet that line works fine when run from the terminal. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing `$SLIDE_PATH` is set in your terminal but not in whatever shell you are using in your script

Comment: I get a similar  error if I remove $SLIDE_PATH and hard code the path- /genetics/ppt/slides/*.xml: No such file or directory

Comment: Does the path exist and do you have all permissions?

Comment: path exists and owned by my account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking what you have.

```
echo *.xml # should list your files
```

If this outputs `*.xml` you're in the wrong place.
Try it this way:

```
for s in "$SLIDE_PATH"/*.xml
do grep -L ppaction://media "$s" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'
done
```

Does that work any better?